# Error on SPWebApplication.WebService.ApplyWeyConfigModifications

Tags: spwebconfigmodification

I've been trying to add a line to my web.config through a EventReceiver on my webpart's Feature. I tried to follow some 'tutorials' ([this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebconfigmodification.aspx), [this](http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/dterrell/archive/2008/10/08/using-spwebconfigmodification-part-1.aspx) and [this](http://blogs.devhorizon.com/reza/2008/01/05/spwebconfigmodifications-top-6-issues/)). It wasn't working, but at least i could deploy the solution.

Sometimes it would delete everything on my web.config and leave only the line that i wanted to add. It was a simple line on `<configuration><appSettings><add key="searchPath" value="http://myVirtualMachineSearchPath" />`

After the update, it would leave me empty with just that one single line on the web.config.

Right now, my code is this:

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
        {
            InsertWebConfigEntries(properties);
        }

        //add all web.config entries 
        private void InsertWebConfigEntries(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
        {
            if (!CheckEntries(properties))
            {
                using (SPSite site = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite)
                {
                    SPWebConfigModification dsEntry = GenerateWebConfigEntry("New config key", "configuration/appSettings",
                        "<add key=\"searchPath\" value=\"http://myVirtualMachineSearchPath\" />", 100);

                    SPWebApplication currentWebApp = site.WebApplication;

                    currentWebApp.WebConfigModifications.Add(dsEntry);
                    currentWebApp.WebService.ApplyWebConfigModifications();
                    currentWebApp.Update();
                }
            }
        }

        //check if the web.config entry exists. If you don't call this method you will get duplicate entries 
        private bool CheckEntries(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
        {
            using (SPSite site = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite)
            {
                SPWebApplication currentWebApp = site.WebApplication;

                Collection<SPWebConfigModification> webConfigEntries = currentWebApp.WebConfigModifications;

                foreach (SPWebConfigModification entry in webConfigEntries)
                {
                    if (entry.Owner == "Owner")
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                return false;
            }
        }

        //new web.config entry 
        private SPWebConfigModification GenerateWebConfigEntry(string modName, string sXpath, string sKey, uint iSequence)
        {
            SPWebConfigModification configMod = new SPWebConfigModification(modName, sXpath);
            configMod.Type = SPWebConfigModification.SPWebConfigModificationType.EnsureChildNode;
            configMod.Name = string.Format("add[@name='{0}']", modName);
            configMod.Owner = "Owner";

            configMod.Value = sKey;
            configMod.Sequence = iSequence;

            return configMod;
        }
```

But now, when I try to deploy the solution, it gives me an error:

```
Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Failed to apply web.config modifications to Web application '3f79bb09-9e0f-4aed-a400-5debe6346440'.
Failed to apply web.config modifications to file 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80\web.config'.
Failed to apply a web.config modification to file 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80\web.config'.  
The specified node "configuration/appSettings" was not found in the web.config file.
```

When i debug the code, my `SPWebApplication.WebConfigModifications` already contains 18 elements that i added on my previous attempts, but i deleted that code and for some reason, i can't evoke the `WebConfigModifications.Clear()` method with success, every time i try to use the `SPWebApplication.Update()` it gives me the error above, even when i don't add any other `SPWebConfigModification`.

Anyone have a idea of what I can do to work with this issue?

I'm sorry if the post is a little confusing, but I'm pretty lost at the moment.

Comment: Have you tried to make the same modifications via PowerShell only? I'd highly recommend doing them in PowerShell over a Feature in a WSP, as the SPWebConfigModification is extremely flaky, many developers have problems with it.

Comment: I might have to go that way James, specially now that I know i'll have to input code on the central administration's web.config too.